# Error: No data value -9.99999999E8 cannot be applied to band #0 of type Short<0,255>, when importing raster in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

[image]I have a question, what does mean the message in the screenshot I uploaded.

```
Error: No data value -9.99999999E8 cannot be applied to band #0 of type Short<0,255>
```

Should a raster dataset have some characteristics before importing it in Google Earth Engine, in the Assets tab? 
My raster is an 8bit raster dataset, which contains values 0, 1 and 10 for some land cover classes.

Comment: It seems strange that the nodata value is outside of the range of 8-bit data. Check the metadata of the file and confirm what the nodata value is set at. Are your data perhaps int32 or int64, instead?

Comment: You are totally right. It was int64. I changed it and I was able to upload the dataset. Thanks!